# What if multiple threads throwing exception in case of Semaphore

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

What will happen if more than one threads throws exception in a semaphore.

Suppose a sempahore can have 10 threads those can enter at a time and thread# 2,5,6,7,9  will throw exception then will other threads which will not throw exception run successfully or they get aborted.

Is it somehow related to AggregatedException class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the other threads are already inside the semaphore when the exception occurs, they will run successfully to completion. If you want them to terminate early, use a [SemaphoreSlim](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Semaphore) object with a [cancellation token](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_Cancellation_Tokens).

Comment: So It means if Suppose among 10 concurrent threads some of them may encounter "divide by zero" then i should cancel all other threads also which haven't faced any exception. is it so ?  +1 for your viewpoint.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta no, it means that you *can* cancel the other threads early if you want to. But you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what you mean by

> throws exception in a semaphore

but probably

> throws exception before releasing the semaphore

in this case the other threads in the group of 10 will run to completion with no problems.
If other threads come in afterwards they may deadlock due to lack of permits.

In any case, semaphores, locks, etc. should be released in a `finally` block to prevent the above, according to the following scheme:

```
acquire
try
{
    risky code
}
finally
{
    release
}
```

Comment: That assumes that whatever resource(s) the semaphore is protecting will be left in a reasonable state by the threads that are throwing exceptions - which can't generally be a safe assumption.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: No, of course not. I was just showing how ensure that the semaphore is released in any case. The OP can implement other safety nets on top of this.